# Crystal Reports 13.0.2 (VS2012), Dynamic Image Loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

The images that should load in the picture object(insert -> picture -> selected 1.jpg) dynamically are not showing up in the report. instead the default image that was selected shows up.(1.jpg)

what I've done was to change the "Graphic location" to "Pic/"+{PICID}+".JPG", plus the same syntax in the hyperlink section.
when i click on the image(hyperlink), it shows up in the browser but not in the report.

i've searched alot and added the handlers in web.config, checked with other images, used an ole paintbrush image, added the "aspnet_client(2.0 and 4.0)" folder to the root, checked the folder permissions of the images and still the same image shows up.

any help would be appriciated

Comment: You can use schema file that reads from data base and fill in the report

Comment: Same problem, @user3719239 I cant find a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="rptAppSettings" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/AppSettings.xsd"   xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/AppSettings.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org  /AppSettings.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-  microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop"   attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo source="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
<DataSource DefaultConnectionIndex="0"   FunctionsComponentName="QueriesTableAdapter"     Modifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class,     Public" SchemaSerializationMode="IncludeSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-  com:xml-msdatasource">
  <Connections>
  <Connection AppSettingsObjectName="Web.config" AppSettingsPropertyName="ConnectionString" IsAppSettingsProperty="true" Modifier="Assembly" Name="ConnectionString (Web.config)" ParameterPrefix="@" PropertyReference="AppConfig.System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.0.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionString.ConnectionString" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</Connections>
<Tables />
<Sources />
</DataSource>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:element name="rptAppSettings" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" msprop:Generator_DataSetName="rptAppSettings" msprop:Generator_UserDSName="rptAppSettings">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="App_Settings" msprop:Generator_UserTableName="App_Settings" msprop:Generator_RowEvArgName="App_SettingsRowChangeEvent" msprop:Generator_TableVarName="tableApp_Settings" msprop:Generator_TablePropName="App_Settings" msprop:Generator_RowDeletingName="App_SettingsRowDeleting" msprop:Generator_RowChangingName="App_SettingsRowChanging" msprop:Generator_RowDeletedName="App_SettingsRowDeleted" msprop:Generator_TableClassName="App_SettingsDataTable" msprop:Generator_RowChangedName="App_SettingsRowChanged" msprop:Generator_RowEvHandlerName="App_SettingsRowChangeEventHandler" msprop:Generator_RowClassName="App_SettingsRow">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="LogoImage"     msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnLogoImage"   msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="LogoImage"    msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="LogoImageColumn"    msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="LogoImage" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
  </xs:choice>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

Comment: the images are stored in directory not the database. the location is accessible by url

Answer (score 0):

push the image(s) into the report as fields of a datatable. this solution requires that you push data into the reports via a DataSet.

if you are binding your crystal report to plain old objects you want to expose a byte[] property for the report to treat that as an image.

You can see these examples: 
 http://aspalliance.com/1097_Importing_Dynamic_Images_to_the_Crystal_Report_without_Database_Overhead_using_Visual_Studio_2005

Comment: Well thank you for suggesting another solution. but this was an obsolete solution since version 11 and it did not answer my question. i'd like to know the problem with the graphic location...